# Nonprimes with $3^{n-1} \equiv 2^{n-1} \pmod n$

Tags: number-theory

Is it true that there are infinitely many nonprime integers $n$ such that $3^{n-1} - 2^{n-1}$ is a multiple of $n$?

Comment: I believe this follows from the existence of infinitely many Carmichael numbers, but maybe there is a more elementary proof.

Comment: I was just writing to refer to pseudoprimes :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I know how to prove it without using of Carmichael numbers.

Take $n = 3^{2^k} - 2^{2^k}$. Then it's not hard to prove by induction on $k$ that $2^k | n - 1$. Hence $3^{2^k} - 2^{2^k} | 3^{n-1} - 2^{n-1}$ (that's true because $a - b | a^r - b^r$ for any natural $a, b$ and $k$).

Answer (score 0):

as Qiaochu Yuan pointed out, take a [Carmichael number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number) *q*; by definition, 3<sup>*q*-1</sup> and 2<sup>*q*-1</sup> are both congruent to 1 mod *q*, so their difference is a multiple of *q*. Since Carmichael numbers are infinite, you are done.

Comment: If q is relatively prime to 3.  I don't know if this occurs infinitely often.

Answer (score 0):

It is true for all n such that $(n,2)=(n,3)=1$ and for which the order of 2 & 3 modulo n is same.